# subsetting data with only entries with in the parentheses

Tags: r

How can i subset data that contains only entries with in the parentheses from description column

```
 data=    ID            description                                   control   
        1814668     glycoprotein 2  (Gp2) (Fy2)                      LMN_2904435
        1791634     claudin 10 (Cldn10), transcript variant 1        ILMN_1214954 NM
        1790993     claudin 10 (Cldn10), transcript variant 2        ILMN_2515816
```

output

```
      ID        description      control    
    1814668     Gp2, Fy2     LMN_2904435
    1791634     Cldn10        ILMN_1214954 NM
    1790993     Cldn10        ILMN_2515816
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
 df2$description <- gsub('.*\\(([^)]+)\\).*', '\\1', df2$description)
```

Or use `bracketXtract` from `qdap`

```
 library(qdap)
 unlist(bracketXtract(df2$description, 'round'))
```

Or

```
 library(qdapRegex)
  unlist(rm_round(df2$description, extract=TRUE))
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset "df2N",

```
 df2N$description <- sapply(rm_round(df2N$description, 
                extract=TRUE),toString)
```

Or using `str_extract`

```
 library(stringr)
 sapply(str_extract_all(df2N$description, 
          perl('(?<=\\()[^)]+(?=\\))')), toString)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need the `?` (and pretty sure you don't actually ;-) )

Comment: @akrun it worked fine. But what if i have two sets of entries in parenthesis. for e.g. in the column description i have (Gp2)   (Fiy)

Comment: @beginner Please do update the post with the relevant information.

Comment: @CathG I tried your code, `gsub('[^)]+\\({01}([^)]+)\\).*', '\\1', df2N$description)
#[1] "Gp2"    "Cldn10" "Cldn10"`

Comment: @akrun i tried your code  'df2N$description <- sapply(rm_round(df2N$description, 
                extract=TRUE),toString)'    but getting :  error in evaluating the argument 'X' in selecting a method for function 'sapply': Error: could not find function "rm_round"

Comment: @beginner It is in `library(qdapRegex)`

Comment: @akrun, I misread the edit (well, didn't really wait for the complete one...) and so I thought the OP just wanted the first value, so `gsub('[^)]+\\({1}([^)]+)\\){1}[^)]+\\({1}([^)]+)\\).*', '\\1,\\2', 'glycoprotein 2  (Gp2) (Fy2)')` to have both values (but doesn't work for the other 2 rows... argh...)...

Comment: @CathG I would use `regmatches/gregexpr` to select those elements within the brackets and then use `gsub` to remove the brackets.  Maybe `gsub` alone function could work,..

Comment: @CathG Also, if there are more than 2 elements in the brackets, this may be longer..

Comment: @akrun, yes, probably for `regmatches/gregexpr`, but I'd love to find a way with `gsub`... although, you're right for the fact there could be more than 2 elements and if we don't know the number of elements beforehand, `gsub` is probably not suited for the task...

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as great as @akrun 's solutions but here is another option, using function `gsub` (twice...) from `base R`:

```
df2$description <- gsub("^,\\s|,\\s$", 
                        "",
                        gsub("^[^(]*\\(|\\)[^()]*\\(|\\)[^(]*$", 
                             ", ", 
                             df2$description, perl=T))
#[1] "Gp2, Fy2" "Cldn10"  "Cldn10"
```

**First**, it's telling R to search for either:

- `^[^(]*\\(`: anything that is not a opening bracket, at the beginning of the
  string, and ending with an opening bracket
- `\\)[^()]*\\(`: a closing bracket followed by anything that is not a bracket, ending with an opening bracket
- `\\)[^(]*$`: a closing bracket, followed by anything that is not an opening bracket and goes till the end of string

and replace it by a comma followed by a space.

**Second**, it replaces the "comma followed by a space" at the beginning and at the end of the string by an empty string.

Comment: Looks like it works, but do you need `{1}`.  I mean `gsub("^,\\s|,\\s$", '', gsub("^[^(]*\\(|\\)[^()]*\\(|\\)[^(]*$", ', ', '(Gp2) (Fy2) glycoprotein (Cy2) lg'))`

Comment: @akrun, thanks :-) I knew there was a way with `gsub`;-). For your first comment: it works whatever the number of `()` is. For the second one, you're right, there is probably no need for `{}`.